Error of Trapezoidal rule difference between Wikipedia (and others) from the source material
Can you please help me understand the leap made in the Wikipedia article/page from the source material?
On the Wikipedia page (and various other sources), the error for the Trapezoidal rule is given as:
$$
\text{error} = \int_a^b f(x)\,dx - \frac{b-a}{N} \left[ {f(a) + f(b) \over 2} + \sum_{k=1}^{N-1} f \left( a+k \frac{b-a}{N} \right) \right] = \frac{f''(\xi)h^3N}{12}=\frac{f''(\xi)(b-a)^3}{12N^2}
$$
However, in the referenced source material [1] (equation 5.1.7), it is given as:
$$
E_n(f) = - \frac{(b - a)h^2}{12} f''(\eta)
$$
Now, naming differences aside, I don't understand where the $1/N^2$ in the Wikipedia article comes from in the last two steps.
[1]: Atkinson, Kendall E., An introduction to numerical analysis., New York: John Wiley & Sons, Inc. xvi, 693 p. $ 58.95 (1989). ZBL0718.65001.

$h=\frac{b-a}{N}$, hence $(b-a)h^2=\frac{(b-a)^3}{N^2}$.

Thanks, @Gonçalo. You're right. I see it now. It was under equation 5.1.4, $h = (b-a)/n$. Thank you! Please post your comment as a solution so I can accept it.
